# Determine number of uses of an app - Android

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to know how many time a user used the app?
basicly i want to do some stuff after 3 uses, 5 uses etc... How can i hold this kind of information after it closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save that in the preferences. The following code opens the preferences, gets the number of times stored in it, and increments it.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
int times = preferences.getInt("openKey", 0);
preferences.edit().putInt("openKey", times+1).commit();
```

You can call this code in your activity's onCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) object to store and get any arbitrary information about your application.

Use the [Context.getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)  method to get and instance of this object.

To edit use the [edit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#edit%28%29) method to get the [editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html). don't forget to call [commit](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) when you are done.

Important note: if the user uninstalls the application the preferences go away to (just something to keep in mind....)

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the it somewhere? Like in a [Database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db), a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or an [XML-File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)?